# SOAPUI generate code with axis2

Tags: java, soap, soapui, apache-axis, soap-client

[image]Am trying to generate java code using `SOAPUI`. I have downloaded `SOAPUI`, and `axis2`. I have set `AXIS2_HOME` and my `JAVA_HOME` is also set. 
When i generate code using `AXIS2` artifacts in `SOAPUI` facing below error

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK/JRE
```

Comment: Just to confirm, does your `JAVA_HOME` point to a JRE or the full JDK home directory?

Comment: @craigcaulfield it points to JDK home directory

Comment: Just to double-confirm, could you post the output path of your `JAVA_HOME` and an image of your soapUI preferences showing the AXIS2 config?

Comment: @craigcaulfield echo of my JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91. Also i have added the image of axis2 config

Comment: Issue was java path. I had multiple java installed and had diferent values in path and JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1):

set full java home path including bin in your soapui.bat

Ex.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\bin\
```

**Path for bat file:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin
```